# How to change a variable within a program

Tags: python, variables, for-loop

Can someone check this code please?  Most of it is working but when they type 'admin' it should allow them to set a new password 'type new password' but then the new password doent save.  Can anyone help me fix it?  Thanks

```
program = ("live")
while program == ("live"):
    password = ("Python")
    question = input("What is the password? ")
    if question == password:
        print ("well done")
    if question == ("admin"):
        n_password = input("What is the new password? ")
        password = n_password
        question = input("What is the password? ")
    else:
        question = input("What is the password? ")
```

Comment: What is a type of `("live")`?

Comment: Just a note: please don't 'save' passwords as cleartext. When a user sets a password, you simply store an hash of that passwort. Next time he 'logs in', you check if the hashes are the same.

Comment: no need to enclose your strings in parens (you're not making a list when you do that).

Comment: Rather than using `input`, you might like to consider `getpass`, it is in the standard library and very easy to use.  By the way, check your logic flow.  The user will be asked for the password twice in  each loop (regardless of `admin` or not).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to move the first `password = ...` line out of the loop:

```
program = ("live")
password = ("Python")
while program ==("live"):
    question=input("What is the password? ")
    if question == password:
        print ("well done")
    if question == ("admin"):
        n_password = input("What is the new password? ")
        password=n_password
        question=input("What is the password? ")
    else:
        question=input("What is the password? ")
```

This ensures that the password is `Python` the first time around but after that it'll use the new value for `password`. Also note that you can remove a few `input()` calls:

```
program = ("live")
password = ("Python")
while program ==("live"):
    question=input("What is the password? ")
    if question == password:
        print ("well done")
    if question == ("admin"):
        n_password = input("What is the new password? ")
        password=n_password
```

Comment: Great help, much appreciated!

Comment: Please remove the unneeded parens from your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put `password = ("Python")` before the beginning of your while loop.